# ObjectContext.LoadProperty is not loading the related entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm having difficulty with `ObjectContext.LoadProperty` (EF 4 Database First) (both the string and expression overloads exhibit the same behavior for me). Given the following simple schema:

```
Product
--------------
ProductId (pk)
...

Order
--------------
OrderId (pk)
...

OrderItem
--------------
OrderId (pk, fk Order),
ItemNumber (pk),
ProductId (fk Product)
...
```

Because I've found it to perform better than `Includes` in my particular scenario, I'm using `LoadProperty` to populate the related entity. For example,

```
Order ord = context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId = 1).FirstOrDefault();

context.LoadProperty(ord, o => o.Items); // Items is the navigation property name for the
                                            OrderItem -> Order relationship

foreach(var i in ord.Items)
{
    context.LoadProperty(i, oi => oi.Product);
}
```

This has been in place for some time and has worked (as you'd expect) just fine. However, this morning we started encountering a scenario where even after calling `LoadProperty`, `i.Product` was still null. `i.ProductId` is valid and I can even load the product explicitly like so:

```
var product = context.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == i.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
```

But `LoadProperty` won't load the object. No exception is thrown, it just simply doesn't load it. I've also tried specifying `MergeOptions.OverwriteChanges` (even though there aren't any), and the results have been predictably the same.

**What could cause `ObjectContext.LoadProperty` to fail silently in this manner?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that this appears to be an issue (if not an outright bug) with the way EF's `LoadProperty` function works.

The `OrderItem` and `Product` tables had values for `ProductId` that differed either by case, trailing spaces, or both. Given SQL Server's default collation, this was legal and referential integrity was maintained. This is why queries for the product worked, but it seems that EF was doing key comparisons internally somewhere and being more stringent about these values.

If you encounter this issue yourself, you can check for trailing spaces by using the T-SQL `DATALENGTH` function in your query and you can compare case by using a different collation.

For example, you can see discrepancies in my above model using this:

```
select
    *

from OrderItem oi

join Product p on p.ProductId = oi.ProductId -- default collation; case and 
                                             -- trailing spaces ignored

where DATALENGTH(oi.ProductId) <> DATALENGTH(p.Product) -- trailing spaces differ
   or oi.ProductId <> p.ProductId COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS -- case differs
```

Note that it may be possible to compare both trailing spaces and character casing using collation only; if anyone knows the name of a collation that does such a thing, feel free to edit this answer or post a comment and I'll update. Until then, this should do what's necessary.

Comment: Yes EF internally matches keys when fixing relations but it uses case sensitive string comparison with no trimming for that.